# How to get zsh to start automatically in Mac iTerm?

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm

I am sure this is a configuration issue, but I cannot find what is wrong. I have zsh and oh-my-zsh installed on my new Mac view homebrew.

When I start terminal it doesn't load zhs theme or autocomplete unless I run `zsh` command to start it. After that all works fine.

However, all the aliases I setup in `.zshrc` file works fine without running zsh and there is no `.bashrc` file in the machine.

How can I make zsh to start automatically when I open iTerm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming; try apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Well, I I can see you would see it that way. On the other hand, zsh is most definitely programming aid for giving bash & docker auto complete even when I am just formatting Docker files with cat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your default shell to zsh.

Using the below command, and type your password

`chsh -s /bin/zsh`

If you want to use brew managed zsh, you should append `/usr/local/bin/zsh` to the end of file `/etc/shells`, then run command `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh`.

Then reopen your iTerm2, done.